# getting error while importing agents, task, process and crew from crewai

Tags: openai-api, agi, autogen, google-generativeai

i am getting error , while importing agents, task, process and crew from crewai
error i am getting - "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType' "
"

code - from crewai import agents , process , crew, Task
error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType'

i tryed it on jupiter notbook as well as vr code